# php pdo query doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I been trying to implement PDO with prepare(), bindParam() and execute() functions to allow a query to be constructed from data entered by the user.

I wanted to display the list of books and then allow the user to filter the list and then see the new list and the full list.

When I enter criteria into the form to search nothing happens. What am I overlooking?

here is the code

```
<?php
        $pageTitle = "Book List";
        $pageHeading = "Book List";
        include_once ('header.php');
        include_once('databaseConnection.php');


        if(isset($_POST['txtSearchBookTitle'])) {
            $db = new DatabaseConnection();
            $db = $db->db_connection;
            $searchTitle = ($_POST['txtSearchBookTitle']);
            $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM tblBook WHERE title LIKE ('%:searchTitle%') ORDER BY title");
            $sql->bindParam(':searchTitle', $searchTitle);
            $sql->execute();
            $result = $sql->fetchAll();

            print_r($result);

            foreach ($result as $row) {
                echo  "<li>" .  " " . $row["title"]. " " . "</li>";
              } 
        }

    ?>
        <form name="searchBookTitle" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Search Books</legend>
                <label for="txtSearchBookTitle">Search by Book Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="txtSearchBookTitle" id="txtSearchBookTitle">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    <?php 
            include_once('getBooks.php'); 
            getBooks(); 
        include 'footer.php';
    ?>
```

Comment: If you are try to run this query in mysql, do you get back the results what you want?

Comment: I ran this SQL on the database 
SELECT title FROM tblBook WHERE title LIKE ('%the%') ORDER BY title

and that returns the results everytime  

I want to change 'the' to myUserVariable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare the inputs this way:

```
$searchTitle = $_POST['txtSearchBookTitle'];
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM tblBook WHERE title LIKE :searchTitle ORDER BY title");
$sql->execute(array(':searchTitle' => '%' . $searchTitle . '%'));
```

Or like this:

```
$searchTitle = $_POST['txtSearchBookTitle'];
$sql->bindParam(':searchTitle', "%{$searchTitle}%");
```

Comment: was it because the % need escaping in the statement?

Comment: @user3608286 no the problem just separate them, if `%` occurs on your search query, that will handle escaping on percents

Answer (score -1):

Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in your fetchAll.. it means it will return the data as an array

So make it like this one

```
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Not defining the fetch mode will result in `FETCH_BOTH` which is an array with keys according to the column and the column index.

Comment: I think this was down voted because I believe fetchAll() returns an associated array by default